# Unlocking scroll positions in a ListView Adapter

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh, unlock

Imagine I'm implementing a simple TODO app with active and inactive elements. These elements are separated in two lists (a list for active elements, another list for inactive elements). I already implemented an adapter which handles the two list views to show the inactive elements on top and the active elements below.

My question is, how can I implement the following (see picture below): First of all I like to display the active elements only. When the user reaches the top of that list view he/she can pull down the list to unlock the inactive elements. The unlocking should be similar to the usual content refreshing like in Google Mail app or the [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) implementation of Chris Banes (So far I'm using the PullToRefresh implementation and I can trigger that event when I pull down for a distance of 50% of the screen size). The part I do have problems with is to smoothly scroll in the list view of the inactive elements.

[image: unlocking hided elements]

**I guess I need the following steps:**

(1) Tell my adapter that it should stop scrolling at the position of the first active element. Do I need to set the inactive elements list view to Visible.GONE for that??

(2) When the user pulls down for a distance of 50% I need to unlock the list view of inactive elements. I think I could use Visible.VISIBLE for that part, but I need to keep the current scroll position while calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. I like to avoid that the adapter jumps on top of the list.

Any suggestions how I can do that? Another idea I had was to use to fragments, each showing a single list view. After pulling down the first list view the fragment of the inactive elements would scroll down. But I think that want work as smooth as I expect it :-)

I'ld appreciate any help!

Best regards, Michael